# How to Capture Fingerprint using Veridis Biometrics SDK?

Tags: vb.net, biometrics

I downloaded Veridis Biometrics SDK for my Futronic FS80 device, how can I capture finger print and save it to my SQL Server database? I know it is very basic but I am new with fingerprint device, I spent much time looking for some tutorials but i failed. Thanks In Advance evryone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the samples folder. The samples are very straight forward to use. You might also want to look through their manual [here](http://www.veridisbiometrics.com/Docs/SDK/VBS_Manual_EN.pdf).

I used the SDK for a project but implemented with Java.